# can't exchange token manually v2.7

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Loopback and 
I'm trying to user auth  for graph api without javascript sdk or passport
I got the code successfully however I can't exchange it with access token

I followed this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#confirm

my get request is https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/dialog/oauth?code={xxxx}&client_secret={xxxx}&client_id={xxx}&redirect_uri={myURL}

myURL is the one used to get the code but not be used again if I understand

If I understand correctly I should it the access_token in the body of the response instead I get this error

```
{
 "error": {
"message": "Unknown path components: /oauth",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 2500,
"fbtrace_id": "HXe+214tGpW"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the docs. The first call is to www.facebook.com in a browser.

See here for an example client https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/services/facebook/FacebookAuthFlow.java

The second should be to something like https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/oauth/access_token

Comment: It worked thanks, however, it's different from the documentation that's odd. for the record I also changed the URL  to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/oauth/access_token  for a JSON response also the GitHub link is demonstrated the OAuth thing  in a good way thanks again

Comment: If you have a mac, "brew install yschimke/tap/oksocial; oksocial --authorize facebook"

Comment: I'm on linux didn't know that uber got Oauth  API it's out of my scope/ use cases  but it's good to know

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = $fb->sendRequest(
        'GET',
        '/oauth/access_token',
        [
          'client_id'     => $config['client_id'],
          'client_secret' => $config['client_secret'],
          'grant_type'    => 'fb_exchange_token',
          'fb_exchange_token' => $short_token
        ],
        $short_token,
        null,
        'v2.7');
```